# Graphics - Generating fabric shadows and folds (simplifying cloth editor in-game)

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, 2d

We are trying to develop a module in a game, that would allow creating custom cloths for users. Such cloths will not be animated and characters in game are also not animated, this should be static image.

The user will be able to draw a shape of cloth, fill it with custom fabric (made also by user). We would like to add a feature that will allow to generate shadows and folds of created cloths as simple as possible...

... but we have no idea how :], our team is made mosly of programmers not graphic designers.

Of course it is possible to make simple graphic editor and allow users to draw semi-transparent objects as shadows and paths as folds, but this would be boring and difficult for users.

**What would be the easiest way (if any) to generate and simulate such shadows on cloths?**

Any ideas, a pointers to good directions where to start will be much appreciated.

*P.S. We was thinking about letting user to draw lines (for folds), and then using some masks - generate some shadows at the edges of cloths and near those lines/folds, but don't know if it is good idea.*

Answer (score 0):

I think you could achieve this with a combination of filters and bitmapData manipulation.

Generating different maps to composite together with a fabric texture to give a convincing final image.

**ConvolutionFilter** to create an emboss effect to give you shadows and highlights.

**DisplacementMapFilter** to create a warping effect to enhance the faux 3d look.

Along with a dose of **BlurFilter** and some different inks during compositing to achieve a realistic blend.

Here's an as3 version of the classic CG water ripple effect that may give you some direction. http://wonderfl.net/c/19lm

Comment: Unfortunately we was thinking about vector graphics, i didn't mention this :>, we use SVG format.

Comment: Right, big difference. You could look at custom gradient fills and strokes, with alpha values to get a blended effect, this will be more cpu intensive to render every frame though. Look at lineGradientStyle and beginGradientFill. Are you targeting flash player or browser/js (asking due to your SVG mention)?

Comment: Flash player, we already have simple SVG parser, a big plus is that we don't need to parse external SVG made by other apps, so it does not need to be 100% valid with standard and 100% complete. We just want nice format to save and load graphics made by users, allowing them to edit already saved graphics etc. Graphics will be mostly static, no animations.

Comment: We had no better idea how to store such user-created vector graphics, allowing to edit and reuse them, the idea was to make custom format based mostly on SVG, so it should be actually called almost-SVG :D...